# How can we remove the duplicate object from list of objects through java

Tags: java

```
List<Student> studentList1 = [Student1,Student2,Student3]
    Student1 and 2 and 3 are the models.
    arg1 = id , arg2 = name
    student1 = [5,"fsd"]
    student2 = [7,"fsf]
    student3 = [5,"fsd"]
```

1. If this is the scenario we need to remove duplicated objects here. Only student1 must be there or student 3 as values are same.
   A new list with the unique objects is the ultimate ouput which is like below.

List studentList2 = [studentObject1,studentObject2]

Comment: implement the `equals` method on the `Student` model, and then use a `Set` instead of a list

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo what if he wants to retrieve them ? then it wont work

Comment: Please post the correct code.

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani he didn't mention that

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo No she should override hashCode() and equals() not just equals()

Comment: yeah @ZahidKhan if it is a `HashSet`

Comment: I think `LinkedHashSet` is good for get rid from duplicate

Comment: What do you mean by `models`

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo there is a contract in the Collection framework that you are violating by overriding equals(). Wherever you are overriding hashCode() you have to have override equals() and vice-versa.

Comment: Although, I am still considered a Junior Java developer, I will try to give your problem a go and post an answer. I believe I have solved a similar problem in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @arshiya this is the easiest solution I can come up with (there are others that come to mind, like using pointers with enhanced for loops, but that is much more complicated). It uses a new Set data structure which will do the removal of duplicates in the background (not explicitly coded by you), as long as you define "what is an equal student?" which happens in the equals() method. I recommend that you take the code below make them as two separate new Java classes and play around, see if this solution works for you.

Here is my Student class:

```
public class Student {
    // Attributes
    int id;
    String name;

    // Constructor/s
    Student(int idGiven, String nameGiven) {
        id = idGiven;
        name = nameGiven;
    }

    // Methods

    // Getters and Setters
    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setID(int newID) {
        id = newID;
        System.out.println("ID changed from " + id + "to " + newID);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
        System.out.println("Name changed from " + name + "to " + newName);
    }

    // Required, the equals method as part of every object in Java can be overridden
    // with the notation below.
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherStudent) {
        // Check if the object given is a student.
        if (otherStudent instanceof Student) {
            // Create a temporary student object so we avoid casting later.
            Student checkedOtherStudent = (Student) otherStudent;

            // If the names are the same then it is the same student. If you want you can do the
            // exact same thing with the ID
            if (this.name.equals(checkedOtherStudent.getName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // If its not a student, print something to be aware of what happened
        else {
            System.out.println("Object provided is NOT  a type of Student.");
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Required for using a set as part of the solution
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    // Optional, but allows you to view the output properly
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student with name: " + name + " and id: " + id;
    }
}
```

And my Main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create example students and fill an ArrayList.
        Student student1 = new Student(1, "Tamila");
        Student student2 = new Student(2, "John");
        Student student3 = new Student(3, "Tamila");
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(student1);
        studentList.add(student2);
        studentList.add(student3);

        // List before any changes
        System.out.println(studentList);

        // Set data structure will only allow unique elements inside by definition, so
        // lets just add our arraylist into the set.
        Set<Student> setOfStudents = new HashSet<Student>(studentList);
        // Empty your student list
        studentList.clear();
        // Refill the student list only with the unique elements from the set
        studentList.addAll(setOfStudents);

        // Test our new list of students without duplicates
        System.out.println(studentList);
    }
}
```

I know some people may find the comments and the large variable names excessive, it's just that I do not know how well into Java the programmer on the other side is. Better to be detailed in my experience.